# Regex Python - Modify random generated string

Tags: python, regex, string, random

I need to read from file, two strings, one 'static' string from file, and one random dynamically generated one, which is also written on a file.

Then, replace one character in the random generated string with another random one.

And repeat the process. Until I get the "static" string which is on a file, in this case "THIS IS A STRING".

I'm pretty lost trying to achieve this, this is what I have so far:

```
import string
import random
import os
import re

file = open('file.dat', 'r')
file=file.read().split(',')
print file

def id_generator(size=28, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
if os.path.exists('newfile.txt'):
   os.remove('newfile.txt')
else:
    file = open("newfile.txt", "w")
    file.write(id_generator())
    file.close()
    if re.search(r"THIS IS A STRING", file):
        print("success!")
```

I'm trying to achieve this with `re` module, since it should read character by character, finding it's position in the random generated string.

Not just comparing but also finding the position of the matching characters (if any)

The `file.dat` file contains the `THIS IS A STRING` string, which I call the 'static' one, it doesn't changes, it should be matched by the random generated ones process .

The `newfile.txt` prints the random generated string.

So, in a nutshell, how can I read the string on `file.dat` character by character, and same goes for the random generated string on `newfile.txt`?

I hope I've explained myself.

Comment: Not sure why you need regular expressions for this, though I don't fully understand the goal. But `str.replace`, `str.index` and string index `str[i]` seem to be enough for purposes.

Comment: Please fix your code block; part of the code falls outside the code block formatting, making things harder to read.

Comment: Done, Sorry, Thank You, Without regex you think? Even character by character?

Comment: You don't need to check if the file exist, and then remove it. `w` will create a file, and if one exists, delete all its contents. You are also running `re.search` against a closed file handle - and that won't give you your expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the least, you should probably change this

```
file=file.read().split(',')
print file
```

and this

```
    if re.search(r"THIS IS A STRING", file):
        print("success!")
```

to this

```
data=file.read().split(',')
print data
```

and this

```
    if re.search(r"THIS IS A STRING", data):
        print("success!")
```

You are losing the file contents when you open the output file:

```
else:
    file = open("newfile.txt", "w")
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You, but I dont understand, your changes are for the 'file.dat' file, not for the random generated one?

Comment: I modified the answer to show you the code that overwrites the file variable.

Comment: So, I have to do something else? Comment that else statement right?

Comment: Just applied your answer is just the same thing, and what if I comment else statement? Do I have to do that? modify that?

Comment: You have to use a different variable to store the file contents. In this case, I suggested the name `data`.

Comment: Yes, I did, but it is the same thing, well maybe I didn't explain myself, sorry about that, I'm going to open a new question, because actually I need to accomplish something and probably need more code to show